# Middleware StartSession regenerate a session after refresh page Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I added these middlewares in the kernel to use Laravel sessions

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    ];
```

However I have a problem, each time I refresh a page, a new session is regenerated while the old one has not yet expired. (The session is a new one because the ID isnt the same loosing my data session and i have a new entry in my table)

I have well

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

in my config file.
While debugging I noticed that my session changed just after

```
$response = $next($request)
```

in StartSession :

```
 protected function handleStatefulRequest(Request $request, $session, Closure $next)
    {
        // If a session driver has been configured, we will need to start the session here
        // so that the data is ready for an application. Note that the Laravel sessions
        // do not make use of PHP "native" sessions in any way since they are crappy.
        $request->setLaravelSession(
            $this->startSession($request, $session)
        );

        $this->collectGarbage($session);

        $response = $next($request);

        $this->storeCurrentUrl($request, $session);

        $this->addCookieToResponse($response, $session);

        // Again, if the session has been configured we will need to close out the session
        // so that the attributes may be persisted to some storage medium. We will also
        // add the session identifier cookie to the application response headers now.
        $this->saveSession($request);

        return $response;
    }
```

I don't really know what this sign does and if it's really the origin of the problem but would you know how I could solve this problem?

Comment: why you say that new session is generated?

Comment: my session cookie is a new one after refresh and i loose my data sesion. And I have a new entry for sure in my table Session

Comment: Why would you want to start the session in the global middleware? API consumers (who will generally use the API routes) generally do not send cookies making the whole exercise pointless. If you have API routes that rely on using the session then maybe they need to change to web routes

Comment: Good question. Actually, I got an error ``Session store not set on request``.
When retrieving session data e.g. using ``$request->session()->all();``.  The solution I found was to add these 2 middlewares but maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: The middleware setup in the [Laravel boilerplate](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Kernel.php) should work for web routes. Instead of doing what you are trying to do you should first check why the session isn't working for your web routes to begin with. Again, do not start the session globally, it is bad practice